# Mule CXF Web service error handling

Tags: mule

This question is on Mule CXF error handling. I have a soap based web service basically this is a validation service that validates an incoming file and reports on any errors in the file. Once validation is unsuccessful i have a catch-exception-strategy which logs the error and sends a email to Prod support team. After validation is unsuccessful i need not call the subsequent steps in the flow. And only the logging and sending an email alert should happen. Shouldn't using a catch-exception-strategy solve the problem ( similar to a try/catch block in Java). But what i notice is the caller is sent a response back and subsequent flow steps are executed

Comment: Depends how validation is done. Config, Mule version...

Comment: The service throws an ValidationException with exception message indicating the cause. The catch-exception-strategy in the service flow logs the error and sends the email alert.After this the service is returning a response to the caller. I am using Mule version 3.4

Comment: OK. So "the caller is sent a response back" seems correct but "subsequent flow steps are executed" is really strange. Without seeing your flow, all this is pure conjecture.

Comment: Please include your config file here for more help.

Answer (score 0):

In your catch exception strategy put an **asynchronous flow** and in that put your logger and smtp to send the mail ... I guess it will solve your problem ...

Since you will be using **asynchronous flow** response shouldn't be there ... Pls let me know if it solve your issue